# ca you suggest circuit to give stimulation to muscles

Tags: voltage

how to design a circuit for convert a 5v dc to 100v impulse. the circuit should be smallest as possible. the output must be an impulse because the circuit is for stimulation of human muscles

Comment: No I "ca" not. Welcome to EE.SE but please note that your post shows no sign of research on your part and is asking for a free design service. You haven't even bothered to check your spelling, capitalise where required, punctuate properly or add a question mark.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a free design service.  If you however have a circuit in mind we'd be glad to help you with understanding it.

I'm not going to recommend any specific circuit, but I am going to mention a few important things you need to consider:

- The heart is a muscle, you need to make sure your stimulation thingy is not going to stimulate that muscle.  You should also avoid stimulating the central nervous center, i.e. the brain and the spine.
- I've seen numbers on how much current is required to command muscles but not voltages, and I also know that the skin's resistance can vary a lot.  You need to regulate the current.
- The circuit needs to be absolutely fool proof:

  - Continuously zapping a muscle may inhibit the subject from releasing him-/herself from your circuit.
  - A subject might touch something grounded, you'll need galvanic isolation.
  - Stick to arms and legs or you might accidentally kill someone.
  - Limit to one limb at a time, otherwise you might get current through more vital organs, e.g. the heart.
  - Limit the voltage so that it will be unlikely that it can supply a dangerous current through more than one limbs plus the heart.

**And if you don't know what you're doing, please don't connect electricity to someone's body.**